# Properties of Pushouts in the category of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I have following question:

$X, X_0, X_1$ and $X_2$ are topological spaces.

Furthermore, $\mu_i:X_0\rightarrow X_i$ and $\alpha_i:X_i\rightarrow X$ morphisms in the category of topological spaces, $i=1,2,$ such that $\alpha_1\circ\mu_1=\alpha_2\circ\mu_2$. And the following diagram is a pushout:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_0 @>\mu_1>> X_1 \\
@V\mu_2VV @VV\alpha_1V \\
X_2 @>\alpha_2>> X
\end{CD}
$$

How can I show that

1) $X=\alpha_1(X_1)\cup \alpha_2(X_2)$,

2) $\alpha_1(X_1)\cap \alpha_2(X_2)=\alpha_1(\mu_1(X_0))=\alpha_2(\mu_2(X_0))$,

3) If $\mu_1$ is injective, so is $\alpha_2$?

Many thanks in advance!

Alex

Comment: "So the following diagramm is a pushout:" is false. That does not follow from the previously stated conditions. Do you want to add it as a condition?

Comment: Hey thanks and sorry for that! I meant it as a condition.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* The pushout is constructed in such a way that the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Top} \to \mathsf{Set}$ preserves it. So you might as well work with sets and maps of sets. Now use the explicit construction of the pushout as $X=(X_1 \sqcup X_2)/(\mu_1(x) \sim \mu_2(x))$.

Comment: When do we have $\mu_1$~$\mu_2?$ How can I define this equivalence relation?

Comment: One means the smallest equivalence relation containing all $(\mu_1(x),\mu_2(x))$, $x \in X$. So one first closes under reflexivity, then symmetry, then transitivity. Thus, $a \sim b$ for $a \in X_1$ (for example) if and only if there is a chain $a = \mu_1(x)$, $\mu_2(x) = \mu_2(x')$, $\mu_1(x')=\mu_1(x'')$, etc. ending with $b$.